# Getting button name as input

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

In this example I am assigning a variable (hsname) the school that is selected when sending the form:

```
<form class="w3-wide" action="/hschool" method="post">
    <input list="hschools" name="hsname" autocomplete="off">
        <datalist id="hschools">
            <option value= "hs1">
            <option value= "hs2">
        </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I then use this value in python (with flask) and to get it I use the following (in a separated .py file):

```
hsname = request.form.get("hsname")
```

The previous is working fine.

In a similar way, I want to assign to a variable the name of the button that the user is clicking (b1 or b2). The following is not working as there is not variable that records the button that the user clicks.

```
<form class="w3-wide" action="/subject" method="post">
            <button class="button button4" name="b1">b1</button>
            <button class="button button4" name="b2">b2</button>
</form>
```

How can I do it?

I know I could use a radio button here but aesthetically I would rather use a normal button. I know I can use the onclick method but what should I write inside so that it stores a variable that is directly sent to flask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send the info to the server as soons as the button is clicked, you can give a `name` and a `value` to an html `<button>` and those will be sent with the form:

```
<form class="w3-wide" action="/subject" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="clicked_btn" value="b1">b1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="clicked_btn" value="b2">b2</button>
</form>
```

Once one of these buttons is clicked, the form will be submitted and the name and value (e.g. `clicked_btn=b1`) will be sent to the server (along with any other inputs in the form).

On the other hand, if you want to just remember the state of the button, so that it behaves like a checkbox or like a radio button, only to be sent to the server when a (different) submit button is clicked, then I suggest actually using a checkbox or a radio button and modifying its appearance using CSS to make it look like a button.

You can also use javascript to store some information into a `<input type=hidden>` input, which will later be sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed! Really appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your button in a form with a hidden input and access the value with `request.form.get("hsname")` or `request.POST.get("hsname)` depending on how flask implements this (i'm more familiar with django).

Note that you will need 1 form+input per buttons

```
<form method="POST" action="some_url/">
    <input type="hidden" name="hsname" value="the_name_of_the_button">
    <button class="button button4" type="submit"></button> 
</form>
```

EDIT: this is html 4.1, for html 5 see zvone's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `id` for each button that can be captured on the client side send to the server via `ajax`:

```
<html>
 <head>   
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head> 
     <input type='text' id='value'>   
     <button class="button button4" name="b1">b1</button>
     <button class="button button4" name="b2">b2</button>
 </form>
  <div id='user_results'></div>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').click(function(even){
         var the_id = event.target.id;
         var user_input = $('#value').val();
         $.ajax({
           url: "/get_user_data",
           type: "get",
           data: {btn: the_id, result:iuser_input},
           success: function(response) {
            $('user_results').html(response);
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
           //Do Something to handle error
         }
        });
       });
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

Then, in your `.py` file, create a route to receive the data from `ajax`:

```
@app.route('/get_user_data')
def get_data():
   button_id = flask.request.args.get('btn')
   user_input = flask.request.args.get('result')
   return '<p>Thanks</p>'
```

Comment: And how can I get this variable from flask? Can I still use something similar to:    hsname = request.form.get("hsname")  ??